# Any difference for a pressure-assisted toilet?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

Can a gravity flush toilet be swapped out for a pressure-assisted toilet? Are there any differences in plumbing, mounting, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there's no difference in plumbing requirements from this [installation guide](http://www.flushmate.com/installation/).

This regular [toilet installation guide](http://www.doityourself.com/stry/bathinstallatoilet) lists the drain and vent requirements:

> it requires its own 2" minimum vent and a drain of at least 3" in diameter

As far as retrofitting a pressure assist vessel into an old gravity flush toilet, I wouldn't try it. Pressure assist toilets are designed differently than gravity flush ones. Flushmate's website warns:

> The FLUSHMATE® Pressure-Assist system **cannot** be retrofitted into a standard, gravity-fed toilet.

There might be a retrofit kit out there somewhere, but I'd be wary about how well it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can. There are no differences on the outside.

There are even some pressure-assist valves that can be retrofitted into existing toilet tanks.